# Reading Data from Firebase...with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase

So, as the title suggests, I am currently working on a rather troublesome problem. Here's the scenario.

I have a Google Spreadsheet containing a template with name, email, and expiration date. However, it contains no actual data. The data itself is located in a Firebase and is constantly changing. My goal, then, is to allow the `script.gs` file attached to my spreadsheet to read from Firebase, either through a timed interval or by using Firebase's typical `dataRef.on('value',function(){});`.

I have already tried using a web app, but Caja makes mincemeat of Firebase's code, which you have to have in order to use the Firebase object. I tried including the Firebase script as a library, and later copied it directly into `script.gs`. Nothing worked.

I believe my problem is largely stemming from the gs environment, that is, the server. However, `cURL` does not seem to work when placed in `script.gs`. Anyway, hopefully one of you has an answer. If you require further clarification, let me know.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to make a call to their REST API using urlFetch to get your data?

Comment: How would I do that exactly? I looked at their documentation, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't use Firebase so I can't give details but I was pretty sure someone would do... Sandy did :-) !! Brilliantly, up voted :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use Firebase with Google Apps Script.  You need to use Google's urlFetch.  [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/)

### CODE EXAMPLE: Get Data

```
var optList = {"method" : "get"};
var recordName = "theUserID";

var rsltList = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://yourFireBaseDB_name.firebaseio.com/" +
recordName + "/.json", optList );
```

In the above example, a **GET** request is made to firebase.  The database you want data from must be included in the URL.  The URL must end with `/.json`.  Your database structure is reflected in the URL.  In the above example, the database has a different record for each user ID, and the user ID is put into the URL.

UrlFetchApp.fetch() method can have one or two parameters.

```
fetch(url, params)
```

[fetch Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

You need to use the advanced parameters to designate what type of request is being sent: For example: **PUT, GET**.  Note: You can't designate a **PATCH** request directly with `UrlFetchApp.fetch`, but you can put an override in the header to send a **PATCH** request.

It's a lot safer using a **PATCH** request.

If you decide to write data to Firebase using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`, it's good to know that using a **PUT** request can overwrite and wipe out all your data if the URL is not configured correctly.

In the above example, the returned data gets put into the variable: `rsltList`

The second parameter of the fetch method is an object.  `{"method" : "get"}`

The object is a `key:value` pair.

Comment: Wow, thanks. A much better and far more concise solution than my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a rather hacky way to do this, but it does the job none the less. I set up a local script to read from the Firebase. Every time a value is added, the script sends an ajax call to a Google form, which has a spreadsheet full of responses. The ajax call simulates a form submission, and viola! I'm able to send information from a client via Firebase to a second client via ajax to a googlesheet where `script.gs` can access the information and act upon it. The best part of this solution IMHO is that I don't have to mess around with Google's paranoid code parsers/mutilators :)