# Saving google sheets data into Firebase using Google Apps script

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script

I'm trying to have my google sheets synced with my firebase database. I'm not very experienced with javaScript, so is it possible using the below method? The idea is that it would automatically sync every time a new row gets created/updated/deleted. I know that I need the script files but not sure how to import them in the .gs file, so that's why it's in the html.
Many thanks!

[image]

[image]

**translate.gs**

```
function saveToFirebase() {
  var config = {
    apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "MY_DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "MY_DOMAIN.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "MY_DOMAIN",
    storageBucket: "MY_DOMAIN.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "MESSAGE_ID"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var database = firebase.database();

  database.ref('food/' + MY_USER_UID).set({
    name: "pizza funghi",
  }); 
}
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the code that you have written in translate.gs working ?

Comment: This should help you get started with reading and writing data to firebase from apps script:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529863/reading-data-from-firebase-with-google-apps-script?rq=1

Comment: Once you have have that under you belt you can look into using triggers to sync your sheet and database using polling...Or if you're really adventurous look into file push notifications with the Drive api...

Answer (score 3):

There is a [third-party libarary](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) which integrates with Firebase's REST API. If you're comfortable using it, this becomes pretty straightforward.

First we'll need to create a tab to track changes. We need the identity of those who make changes, so we have to break this into two parts - a simple `onEdit` trigger which runs as the modifying user, and an installable trigger which I'll call `uploadChanges`. The latter is what talks to Firebase.

1. Create a tab called `changes`
2. Add a frozen row with the following headers:

   - Uploaded
   - User
   - Value

[Install the third party Firebase library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase)

1. Begin by clicking **Resources > Libraries** in the script editor, then pasting `MYeP8ZEEt1ylVDxS7uyg9plDOcoke7-2l` in the "Find a Library" box. Hit Save.
2. Opt for stability by choosing the latest public release, or choose the latest release (I chose latest while writing this).
3. Click **OK**
4. Now would be a good time to peruse the [reference docs](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/reference) so you know what I'm up to in the below instructions :-)

Set up [security](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-via-oauth-2-access-token) (I'm assuming you want this script to run as you)

1. Make your Google account (which runs the script) be at least an *Editor* for your Firebase project.
2. Set the appropriate [authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) for your App Script project:

   1. Go to **File > Project Properties > Scopes** in the App Script editor
   2. Select **View > Show manifest file** (the manifest file is usually hidden by default)
   3. Add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database` to the `oauthScopes` array (add it if it's not already there)
   4. Save the manifest file. Next time you run the script you'll get a pop-up asking about permissions.

The equivalent of your `translate.gs` above, which always just sets your food to 'pizza funghi`, would look like this:

```
function saveToFirebase() {
  var dbUrl = "MY_DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com";  // Set appropriately
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();    // Depends on security setup above
  var firebase = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(dbUrl, token);
  newData = {
    name: "pizza funghi",
  };
  firebase.setData('food/' + MY_USER_UID, newData);
}
```

*But* you said you wanted to update Firebase on every save. To do this you really just want to rip off one of the various `onEdit` [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) floating around the net. The resulting `onEdit` should look something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // First get stuff about the edit. 
  // This approach only gets the top left cell of a multi-cell edit.
  var editRange = e.range;                  // The edited range
  var newValue = editRange.getValue();      

  // Next, who is the editor? Remove the `split` for full email.
  var username = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().split('@')[0];
  if (username == '') {
    username = SOME_REASONABLE_DEFAULT;     // Or give up if you wish
  }

  // Finally save the change
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                .getSheetByName('changes')
                .appendRow([false, username, newValue]);
}

function uploadChanges() {
  // Attach to Firebase
  var dbUrl = "MY_DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com";  // Set appropriately
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();    // Depends on security setup above
  var firebase = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(dbUrl, token);

  // Get content of changes tab
  var changeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                  .getSheetByName('changes');
  var changeData = changeSheet.getDataRange()
                              .getValues();
  // Upload all new-to-us changes
  for (var i = 1; i < changeData.length; i++) {
    if (changeData[i][0]) {
      continue;               // We already uploaded this one
    }
    changeData[i][0] = true;  // Optimistically assume we'll succeed       
    var newData = {
     name: changeData[i][2]
    };
    var username =  changeData[i][1];
    firebase.setData('food/' + username, newData);
  }
  // Blanket update of change-data sheet to update upload status
  changeSheet.getRange(1, 1, changeData.length, changeData[0].length)
             .setValues(changeData);

}
```

Lastly, set up some triggers.

1. Choose **Edit > Current Project's Triggers** in the script editor
2. Add a new trigger for `onEdit`

   - Choose `onEdit` from the leftmost **Run** dropdown
   - Choose `From spreadsheet` in the **Events** dropdown
   - Then choose `On edit` in the rightmost dropdown
3. Add a new trigger for `uploadChanges`

   - Choose `uploadChanges` from the leftmost **Run** dropdown
   - Choose `Time-driven` from the **Run** dropdown
   - Set up a schedule that's appropriate to your needs

EDIT: My original script had you doing everything in `onEdit`, which tehhowch correctly points out won't work since we're talking to another service. I've updated to stage to a "changes" tab which I include in setup. My new approach maintains a perpetual record of old uploads; for performance you might instead choose to just clear the `changes` sheet once you've done the upload.

Comment: `onEdit(e)` will not be sufficient. `myFunctionWithAnInstalledOnEditTrigger(e)` will be.

Comment: The downside of an installable trigger is that it'll run as you, the installer, instead of as the person doing the edit. What's wrong with this all being in an onEdit? I'm happy to edit my answer (natch)  EDIT: Oh I see the problem is likely calling a service that needs authorization.